# User profile should be consistent when displaying a lack of associated accounts

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, association

Compare [this user's associated accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126?tab=accounts#tab-top) with [this user's associated accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146894?tab=accounts#tab-top). The former includes a "No accounts matching this OpenID" message similar to what an individual user might find on their own account. The latter shows no such messages for the other sites.

The inconsistency of the message implies that in at least one of those cases, there is an account matching that OpenID that isn't associated. But if the user didn't want to associate accounts (and we are in fact allowed to manually do so), then why should Stack Overflow hint at the existence of sister accounts? I've spotted both kinds of display more than once, so neither version is limited to a single user.

Showing no message probably looks nicer.

Comment: I've just checked the accounts you link to and it looks like this has been implemented.

Comment: @ChrisF That's because Tony updated his associations. I've cleared my association with Server Fault, it should be if you view any of my non-SF accounts. I've changed the link now.

Comment: And if, for whatever reason (I can't see because I can't log out on this machine), the meta profile isn't showing the *desired* undesired behavior, then my [Super User profile](http://superuser.com/users/37191?tab=accounts#tab-top) definitely does!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packaged alongside the [grid account display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58626/display-associated-accounts-in-a-grid) came the resolution of this bug. Bumping for [status-completed] and to rid this from the unanswered tab.