# Question migration linked account behaviour

Tags: support, migration, linked-accounts

I just migrated the following question from SO to SU: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066044/change-the-origin-coordinates-in-gimp

- On SO, it was posted by https://stackoverflow.com/users/180573/purecharger
- On SU, the migration attached it to https://superuser.com/users/35887/user35887

These two accounts don't seem to be related (according to the "accounts" tab on either user profile page).

The question is: Was this the correct behaviour, and if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of cheatery, but based on the behavior demonstrated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51760/user-profile-should-be-consistent-when-displaying-a-lack-of-associated-accounts), I can guess that those two accounts most likely have the same OpenID.

The presence of the "No accounts matching this OpenID at Super User" and its Stack Overflow equivalent reveal that the opposing site *does* have an account with a matching OpenID. But there's no solid proof that they correspond from just that.

However, judging from the fact that they have the same avatar, and the migration behavior, they are in fact related. The user has simply decided not to have them associated.

Comment: Good point about the same gravatar, I didn't notice that.