# Linked Stack Exchange accounts all look the same in accounts tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, profile-page, linked-accounts

I notice that linked Stack Exchange 2.0 accounts all look the same in the accounts tab of a user's profile. I understand that [all SE sites in beta look the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same), but can anything be done to make the accounts tab in the user profile more useable?

Screenshot of what I'm talking about:

http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/377/seflair.png

Comment: It's because all the beta sites share the same icon. If the site takes off it will get it's own icon.

Comment: @ChrisF: I understand *why* it's happening, I'm just wondering if anything can be done to make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry - that will be me skim reading posts again.

Comment: Now that the betas have unique favicons, this question makes no sense. Voting to close as too localized.

Comment: +1 to this request for better differentiation on the linked accounts page. Even with unique favicons, I still have to stare at the tiny icon and try to decipher it, or (more likely) roll over the link to see the URL its pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to each "Related account" flair, it spells out the *name* of each site:

- Copy Profile from Web Apps
- Copy Profile from Gaming
- Copy Profile from Webmasters
- Copy Profile from Cooking
- ...etc.

Is that missing from your Accounts tab?

Comment: That's only going to apply when looking at your own. If I, or anyone besides Kip, were to look at Kip's profile, we would need to hover over the link and read the URL to know which one it corresponds to.

Comment: To be more precise, that only shows up for your own account OR if you're a diamond mod. @Grace

Comment: You guys get to force-copy our profiles, @mmyers? Does that mean you also see our [unassociated but same OpenID accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51760/user-profile-should-be-consistent-when-displaying-a-lack-of-associated-accounts), too?

Comment: @Grace Note: Yep, that too. Since we can edit any part of your profile anyway, that's really just a convenience.

Comment: Interesting, @mmyers. I learn something new about the system every day.

Comment: @Grace Note: Ah, yes. You *would not* see the name on other people's accounts. In that case, I cannot see any downside to including the full site name next to the flair list.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: yes, those links show up in my own profile, but not when i view others' profiles. (i took the screenshot in chrome's porn mode because i didn't want to single out another user.)

Comment: I don't see these links. Have they been removed since the above answer was posted?