# Show site names in plain text on related accounts tab

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, profile-page

Since the number of sites are increasing almost every day now, when looking at the related accounts tab of a user it can be pretty hard to find what you're looking for. For example, if I have a look at [Jeff's profile here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1?tab=accounts#tab-top) and want to check out his profile on SuperUser, it takes me a while to find the correct little icon (actually, I might not even remember what it looks like for all sites).

And it's of course even worse for the beta sites. I actually have to move the mouse and check the mouse over text of every beta site.

Could we please put the name in plain text in there somewhere?

Comment: Especially as all the beta sites have the same icon.

Comment: Related, but this one is focused on the Beta sites specifically: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57791/linked-stack-exchange-accounts-all-look-the-same-in-accounts-tab.

Comment: @Grace Note: Yeah, the identical beta icons is part of the issue. I would like plain text regardless of whether that one is fixed though.

Comment: Tool tips don't work for me on the related accounts so I sometimes have to guess which on is which.