# Display associated accounts in a grid

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, linked-accounts

Displaying one flair box per line didn't take up much space when there were only four sites, but now there are a lot more and it takes some scrolling to see them all, this can be seen by looking at [Jeff Atwood's associated accounts.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1?tab=accounts)

Instead I suggest displaying them in a grid:

[image: Flair in a grid.]

Obviously there would still need to be space for the **copy profile** buttons, but these could be displayed underneath the flair or in a popup similar to the buttons to add tags as **interesting** or **ignored**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting timing .. Jarrod just checked this in and it will go out tonight.