# Copy Profile to Related Accounts button is displayed in all user pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, profile-page, linked-accounts

[image: Weblog's profile on SO as seen as logged in as badp]

Comment: [Larger image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Copy%20Profile.png)

Comment: [Related change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58626/display-associated-accounts-in-a-grid) for the Linked bar

Comment: +1 - Repro'd with your profile here on meta.

Comment: I really need to get that superuser account deleted. What a terrible Q&A that turned out to be.

Comment: Here's a very similar bug that was reported (by me :D) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51219/when-viewing-related-accounts-on-accounts-tab-of-a-users-profile-the-clear-all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh, my bad - at least the server ensures this action can't be performed :)

This has been fixed.